# Batch update menu_order attribute alphabetically

Tags: functions, pages

Is there a way to batch update the page order attribute of all children of a specific parent, each time a new child is added?

More simply, is there a way to loop through pages and change the sort attribute so they are alphabetical?

For instance....

- Page Title A - sort order 0
- Page Title C - sort order 0
- Page Title B - sort order 0

Would become...

- Page Title A - sort order 1
- Page Title C - sort order 3
- Page Title B - sort order 2

And would ultimately be displayed in the admin as...

- Page Title A - sort order 1
- Page Title B - sort order 2
- Page Title C - sort order 3

Comment: you want this sort on the admin page of the list ?

Comment: Yes, the admin page. I am talking about updating the sort order attribute of a page. The "order" field under "page attributes."

Comment: on the admin page, the list is already sorted by title. you don't need to use the "order" field

Comment: The admin list can be sorted by title but, if you have a hierarchy, the hierarchy is flattened. I want to preserve the hierarchy,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully this helps someone else

Dont forget to change "your_post_parent_id_here" with the parent id of your choosing.

```
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->query( 'SELECT @i:=-1' );
    $result = $wpdb->query(
        "
        UPDATE wp_posts SET menu_order = ( @i:= @i+1 ) WHERE post_parent = 'your_post_parent_id_here' ORDER BY post_title;
        "
    );
```

Comment: Glad you solved your own question, be sure to click the checkmark next to your answer after two days.